# Splitting a stream in a functional way

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting

There's a following snippet in a merge sort routine

```
val m = xs.length / 2
val (l, r) = xs.splitAt(m)
streamMerge(streamSort(l), streamSort(r))
```

Is there a more functional (and lazy) way to split a stream into two? I've tried porting splitting routine from here http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_(Haskell) but it causes the crash with stack overflow.

Comment: What is `xs` here? It cannot be stream as then `xs.length` or `splitAt` will never terminate.

Comment: @Jatin it *can* be a stream, it just cannot be an *infinite* stream.  Streams do not have to be infinite - it just happens that they are a useful way to deal with infinite sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possibilities: Don't use length or don't use a stream.

### Don't use length

Length is a strict function for streams, so you can't do it. But there are multiple non-strict possibilities:

1. Use a probabilistic approach
2. Use each n-th element

#### The probabilistic approach

Take the first three elements from the stream. When there are less than three, is does not make any sense to split in the first place. Then split on the first element that is greater than these three, using `Stream.partition(_ > biggestElement)`.

This will usually work quite well but will have problems on special data constellations (e.g. input already sorted).

#### Use each n-th element

Split the streams evenly, but not in the middle. Use `Stream.zipWithIndex.partition(_._2 %2 == 0)` to get the two streams.

This might be a good approach if you are offloading some parts of the sorting over the network to other nodes.

### Don't use a stream

Your algorithm might run much faster when you simply don't use a stream, but a data structure where getting the size is cheap.

If you use a mutable collection, you can even [sort in place](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.5514&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This should be the fastest way when you have all your data locally (e.g. in RAM or in a memory mapped file).

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent answer! Would you mind looking at another related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944524/fast-functional-merge-sort?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to implement `split` as in the reference, you'll have to make `go` tail-recursive.

Normal implementation (more or less copied):

```
def go[A](v: (Stream[A], Stream[A])): (Stream[A], Stream[A]) = v match {
  case (x #:: xs, _ #:: _ #:: zs) =>
    val (us,vs) = go((xs,zs))
    (x #:: us, vs)
  case (xs, _) => (Stream.empty, xs)
}
```

This does overflow the stack.

Now we just make it tail recursive:

```
def go[A](v: (Stream[A], Stream[A]), acc: Stream[A]): (Stream[A], Stream[A]) = v match {
  case (x #:: xs, _ #:: _ #:: zs) =>
    go((xs,zs), x #:: acc)
  case (xs, _) => (acc.reverse, xs)
}
```

Now call:

```
go((x,x), Stream.empty)
```

And you get a lazy split without the stack overflowing (while testing I first fill up my memory).

#### UPDATE

As my comment mentions, this last solution does not work with infinite streams. The problem in this case is the right side of the result: In order to know the resulting stream (which is just the tail of the original), we have to fully evaluate the original stream.

An implementation that allows for infinite streams makes this apparent:

```
def split[A](x: Stream[A]) = {

  def goL(v: (Stream[A], Stream[A])): Stream[A] = v match {
    case (x #:: xs, _ #:: _ #:: zs) =>
      x #:: goL(xs, zs)
    case (xs, _) => Stream.empty
  }

  def goR(v: (Stream[A], Stream[A])): Stream[A] = v match {
    case (x #:: xs, _ #:: _ #:: zs) => goR(xs, zs)
    case (xs, _) => xs
  }

  val tup = (x,x)
  (goL(tup), () => goR(tup))

}
```

You can see the fundamental differences between the left and right side:

- The left side is not tail-recursive, but does not overflow the stack, because the recursive `goL`-call is wrapped in a closure by the compiler (a "hidden" version of the trampoline pattern)
- The call to `goR` is manually wrapped in a closure since otherwise the call to `goR` does not terminate.

This works nicely except for the closure wrap of the right stream. This can be mitigated by providing a wrapper/view around stream, that only evaluates the underlying stream (i.e. the `Stream` object itself) once it is used.

The code above can be used as follows:

```
val (a,b) = split(Stream.continually(1))
println(a.head) // > 1

val (c,d) = split(Stream.fill(1000000)(1))

println(c.size)    // > 500000
println(d().size)  // > 500000
```

Comment: Note that this will not work on infinite streams. I'll see if I can figure out how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

You're already doing it the right way. It makes no sense to try to do merge sort lazily. You've already forced your whole stream when you called `xs.length`, so trying to use a lazy method to split it won't make a difference.

What you *could* do is make the `streamMerge` function lazy. As you merge the sorted sublists together, you only need to know the first element of each of the two streams, so you can lazily determine which element is smallest as you combine the streams. Here's what I was thinking:

```
def streamMerge[T](xs: Stream[T], ys: Stream[T])(implicit ord: math.Ordering[T]): Stream[T] = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) ys
  else if (ys.isEmpty) xs
  else {
    if (ord.lteq(xs.head, ys.head))
      xs.head #:: streamMerge(xs.tail, ys)
    else 
      ys.head #:: streamMerge(xs, ys.tail)
  }
}

def streamSort[T](xs: Stream[T])(implicit ord: math.Ordering[T]): Stream[T] = xs match {
  case Stream.Empty => xs
  case Stream(_) => xs
  case _ => {
    val m = xs.length / 2
    val (l, r) = xs.splitAt(m)
    streamMerge(streamSort(l), streamSort(r))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thing is I don't want to force evaluation of the stream and avoid using `length` as the Haskell version does (merge routine is exactly the same as yours). Also, somehow the sort is still lazy - accessing the last element is much slower than accessing the first.

Comment: @synapse There is no such thing as a lazily-evaluated but known-length list/stream in Scala (but you need to know the length to merge-sort). Further, if you think of it: To get the smallest element, you'll need to evaluate all elements first. Only the sorting itself can be lazy and this solution already does that.

Comment: @gzm0 Well, you obviously need to evaluate the collection to sort it but you don't have to do it at the start. Check out Haskell implementation of merge sort I've linked in question.

Comment: @synapse This is not my point: Even the Haskell solution will have to evaluate the whole collection as soon as you request the first element of the sorted list. So you wont gain anything against for example making the sorted list/stream a lazy val.